# Search for a Node text and insert value in xml using python

Tags: python, xml, scripting

I have an XML file generated as part of my release build, i need to change my build numbers by searching the application names iteratively using python script.

My xml file is

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Dependency>
 <IGDeployment>
<Application buildnum="15.9.0.2" name="accesschecker"/>
<Application buildnum="15.9.0.2" name="AlertMonWeb"/>
<Application buildnum="15.9.0.2" name="Berlin"/>
<Application buildnum="15.9.0.2" name="DeliveryMonWeb"/>
<Application buildnum="15.9.0.2" name="FOValidator"/>
<Application buildnum="15.9.0.2" name="hainftomcat1oraclejdk16"/>
<Application buildnum="15.9.0.2" name="inftomcat1jdk16"/>
<Application buildnum="15.9.0.2" name="inftomcat1oraclejdk16"/>
<Application buildnum="15.9.0.2" name="LogViewerWeb"/>
<Application buildnum="15.9.0.2" name="nsaadmin"/>
<Application buildnum="15.9.0.2" name="PrismConsole"/>
<Application buildnum="15.9.0.2" name="PrismStreamServlet"/>
<Application buildnum="15.9.0.2" name="ProviewAdminGui"/>
<Application buildnum="15.9.0.2" name="replication"/>
<Application buildnum="15.9.0.2" name="ReplicationMon"/>
<Application buildnum="15.9.0.2" name="ReporterTool"/>
<Application buildnum="15.9.0.2" name="ResultHistoryMonWeb"/>
<Application buildnum="15.9.0.2" name="SAPRefreshTool"/>
<Application buildnum="15.9.0.2" name="securityadmin"/>
<Application buildnum="15.9.0.2" name="SECURITYmon"/>
<Application buildnum="15.9.0.2" name="stylesheet"/>
<Application buildnum="15.9.0.2" name="transauthadmin"/>
</IGDeployment>
</Dependency>
```

My python script should take application names as parameters and update the given buildnum. Please suggest.
Thanks.